# Right allignment of text in imagettftext function

Tags: php

I am creating images with some text, when rotation is 0 then its fine but when `rotation is  > 0` then image looks are bad due to text alignment, because by default alignment is left.Since each and every value is dynamic so we can not fix it,please help me.

```
$message = 'Thanks, Deep, for making time to have a coffee today Purushottam';
$no_of_characters_line = $temp_data['no_of_characters_line'];
$lines = explode('|', wordwrap($message, $no_of_characters_line, '|'));
// Starting Y position and X position
$y = $temp_data['position_from_top'];
$x = $temp_data['position_from_left'];
$font_size = $temp_data['font_size'];
$rotation_angle = $temp_data['rotation'];
$line_height = $temp_data['line_height'];   

foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
    imagettftext($im, $font_size,$rotation_angle, $x, $y, $black, $font, $line);
    // Increment Y so the next line is below the previous line
    $y += $line_height;
    }
```

I am also attaching example template.[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of how the text renders undesirably?

Comment: You need to adjust $x and $y. $x= horizontal pixel, $y= vertical pixel

Answer (score 0):

You can use [imagettfbbox](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) to calculate the string size in pixels. Then, with the width you will be able calculate the offset required to align the text to the right. Also, check out the [imagettftext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) documentation for some examples of text alignment.